# Start "Chromium" automatically on booting the Pi3 with Raspbian JESSIE

Tags: linux, chromium, raspberry-pi3, autostart

I have a problem.

My goal is that the browser will automatically start up in fullscreenmode and don't go to screensaver mode when I reboot the Pi.

The Pi OS: Raspbian Jessie 
Version: September 2016
Kernel Version: 4.4

I already tried with:

> Adding:
>
> @/usr/bin/chromium --kiosk --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-restore-session-state "http://www.domain.com"
>
> to the end of ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

and

> sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
>
> @chromium –kiosk http://www.domain.com
>
> @xset s noblank
>
> @xset s off
>
> @xset –dpms

But nothing worked.
And everything I found doesn't work :(

Can someone help me pls.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay I fixed it like this now:

> sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
>
> @xset s noblank
>
> @xset s off
>
> @xset –dpms
>
> @chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk http://www.domain.com

and it works.
The funnyest thing is: I tried this allready but then it didn't work. xD

Comment: When I put these lines. after restarting my RPi3 shows me a blank black screen and courser only.

Comment: the `--incognito` is actually not needed. It starts the browser in *incognito* mode, which forgets about the passwords you typed. So if you (like me) have to login into the webpage makes more sense to save the password in the browser and start it in normal kiosk mode so you don't need to enter it every time

Comment: Worked for me where nothing else seemed to.

Answer (score 9):

```
cp /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Edit it as

```
#@xscreensaver -no-splash  # comment this line out to disable screensaver
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk http://localhost/
```

Then, reboot it.

```
sudo reboot
```